# Find Duplicates and Set Value to True

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a script that sets the value to True for only one of the matching rows. There are two sheets within the same spreadsheet. I have the script check the one sheet against the other for matching value. The problem is it only puts the True next to the last matching value, not all of the different matching values. How do I have it find all possible duplicates and put True next to each one. The values it's looking for are actually registration codes; if someone unregisters they put in their reg code and it will match their registration line in the registration sheet.

```
function findDuplicates() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheetR = ss.getSheetByName("Registration");
  var sheetCR = ss.getSheetByName("Cancel Registration")
  var dataR = sheetR.getDataRange().getValues();
  var dataCR = sheetCR.getDataRange().getValues();
  var newData = new Array();
  var headerRow = 1;
  for (var i = 1; i < dataR.length && i < dataCR.length; ++i) {
      var rowR = dataR[i];
      var rowCR = dataCR[i];
      var duplicate = false;
          if (rowR[9] === rowCR[8]) {
              duplicate = true;
          }
  }
  if (duplicate = true) {
      sheetR.getRange(headerRow + i, 11).setValue("True");
  }
}
```

Updated Code:

```
function findDuplicates() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheetR = ss.getSheetByName("Registration");
  var sheetCR = ss.getSheetByName("Cancel Registration")
  var dataR = sheetR.getDataRange().getValues();
  var dataCR = sheetCR.getDataRange().getValues();
  var headerRow = 1;
  for (var i = 1; i < dataR.length && i < dataCR.length; i++) {
      var rowR = dataR[i];
      var rowCR = dataCR[i];
      var duplicate = false;
          if (rowR[9] === rowCR[8]) {
              duplicate = true;
          }
          if (duplicate === true) {
              sheetR.getRange(headerRow + i, 11).setValue("True");
          }
  }
}
```

Update:

```
function findDuplicates() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheetR = ss.getSheetByName("Registration");
  var sheetCR = ss.getSheetByName("Cancel Registration")
  var dataR = sheetR.getDataRange().getValues();
  var dataCR = sheetCR.getDataRange().getValues();
  var headerRow = 1;
  for (var i = 1; i < dataR.length; i++) {
      for (var j = 1; j < dataCR.length; j++) {
          var rowR = dataR[i];
          var rowCR = dataCR[j];
          var duplicate = false;
              if (rowR[9] === rowCR[8]) {
                  duplicate = true;
              }
              if (duplicate === true) {
                  sheetR.getRange(headerRow + i, 11).setValue("Y");
              }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `if (duplicate = true)` is outside the for loop. Since it's calculating the row based off of the value of `i`, it only changes the value for the last value of `i` which is the last duplicate element found in the sheets. So, I would advise you to move it into the for loop.

Tested the code with the above mentioned changes and everything works as desired. Also, your code currently runs 11 row over the limit. That is, if your row 12 is the last row with data and 13 is empty, it setting the value of column in row 13 as `TRUE` as well. Changing `++i` to `i++` in the for loop, takes care of this problem as well.

And last but not the least, your declaration of if statement requires to be `duplicate ==  true` and not `duplicate = true` since the first one is checking whether the value of duplicate is true or not, the second one is actually assigning the value of duplicate to be true.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I changed the ++1 to 1++, put the if statement inside the for loop (tried this before, never worked) and changed the duplicate = true to duplicate == true. Nothing happened. I left it that way, but changed the duplicate == true back to one = and it placed three Ys in the row position of the Cancel Registration sheet, row 1, 2, 3. There should only be two Y's since theres only two matching registrations in the registration sheets. In the registration sheet they are in rows 3 and 5.

Comment: for some reason my if statement wasn't the same (the first one with rowR[9]...) I changed it to that with your other changes and now it only puts one Y in the first duplicate spot, and not the second lol.

Comment: Hmm... strange.. because I tested the code out and it is working perfectly on my end. Use Logger.log statements to make sure you are referencing the correct cells. Also, can you update the code with your changes here?

Comment: It works. Make sure the cells you're referring to in the statement `if (rowR[9] === rowCR[8])` are correct. Keep in mind, your values are stored in an array, so if you're comparing values in column 9 and column 8 it would actually be rowR[8] and rowCR[7] respectively.

Comment: yep they are correct. It's actually column J and I, so 10 & 9. I'm not sure if it makes a difference, but the values it is comparing are unique codes. Someone registers and then a unique code is created and in column J next to their registration from the form. If/when that same person cancels their registration it puts all of the same info including the registration code in the Cancel Registration sheet. So that next duplicate isn't the same code as the first. Person A registers then cancels, then person B registers then cancels. It's only marking the first duplicate reg code.

Comment: Well, are your other registration codes in the cancellation sheet in the same row as the registration sheet? That is, if the person with registration code abc123 in registration sheet is on row 9, your current code will check row 9 in cancellation sheet for the same registration code and see if it is cancelled. If that makes sense.

Comment: No they are in different spots. My orginal put the mark next to the last one and your corrections put it on the first instance. Neither do both. There would be no way to make them be in the same row position, since people register and only some might cancel, if that makes sense.

Comment: Yeah.. so I thought. So you'd have to modify your code to look for registration codes by iterating through all rows for each registration code. Your current code is comparing values for same rows. But that'll be a separate question in itself.

Comment: should I post that as a new question, or do you know how I can change the code to do that? I'm learning as I go. My script project has a lot of different functions.

Comment: I made the first for() = (var i = 1; i < dataR.length; i++) and created a second one for (var j = 1; j < dataCR.length; j++) {}. Also, changed var rowCR = dataCR[i]; to var rowCR = dataCR[j];. I updated the original question w/ changes. Seems to work.

Comment: This looks fine. Had it been Java I would've suggested much better performing data structures but this looks good. Glad to hear it's working though. Hope this is resolved then. :)

Comment: Hmmm wish it had been java then, so I could have learned to make it better. Thank you for all your help. :-)